# What would a language spoken by a tortoise-like sapient species sound like?

Tags: creature-design, language, species

In my world, there is a species of massive bipedal (with a hunchbacked gait because of their shell) turtles with human-level intelligence (I do not mean humans with profound intellectual disability like people with Cri du Chat syndrome, I mean humans with any intelligence labels). They are as social as lemurs (they even have a matriarchal system like them). They are somewhat a Koopa pastiche from Nintendo's *Mario*.

In real life, EVERY language has some sort of complexity and uniqueness to it.

So, I wonder what would a spoken language of a *Testudines* species sound like? Note: there would be fewer body language than human communication, since they would have short digits with long claws. Compared to humans, these turtles have a worse sense of hearing, but an improved sense of smell, and of eyesight (they are tetrachromats). They also have powerful lungs, a good breath control, and large sinuses. They still do not have teeth, but a sharp beak like real life turtles.

Comment: French obviously, because why not?

Comment: Those animals are very obviously highly evolved Testudines, to the point that most of their anatomy is profoundly different from real-world turles. Please edit the question to include a description of their phonatory apparatus and their auditory system. (Because real-world Testudines have a feeble excuse for a phonatory apparatus and, by mammalian standards, a very low-performance and low-fidelity auditory system.) (If you really want to discuss a language suitable for the phonatory and auditory capabilities of real-world Testudines, then say so. It surely won't be melifluous...)

Comment: VTC. I concur with AlexP: you need to specify the anatomy and physiology before I can tell you what their language sound like.

Comment: "Social as lemurs" is unenlightening. Just say what you mean bro.

Comment: Very sorry but this really is anyone’s guess. Our language barely has good descriptors for existing languages, and you want an objective description of tortoise language? VTC.

Answer (score 2):

**Squeak Squeak Squeak**

[image]

Turtles don't talk much. The one exception is when the turtle gets excited by a piece of fashionable footware.  [When that happens they are known to squeak.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nydbYuJEQqU)

This turtle appears be French. So as Pellinore points out, if you run the squeaks through the universal translator you might get something like "C'est ma chassure! C'est ma petite ami! Laissez-moi tranquille!"